# Mixing explicit and implicit joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to execute the query bellow but I'm getting the error: The multi-part identifier 'T2.ID' could not be bound.

```
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                T4.ID 
        FROM    dbo.TABELA1 T1, 
                dbo.TABELA2 T2, 
                dbo.TABELA3 T3, 
                dbo.TABELA4 T4 
                INNER JOIN dbo.TABELA5 T5 ON T4.ID = T5.ID 
                INNER JOIN dbo.TABELA6 T6 ON T5.ID = T6.ID 
                INNER JOIN dbo.TABELA7 T7 ON T6.ID = T7.ID
                INNER JOIN dbo.TABELA8 T8 ON T7.ID = T8.ID AND <b>T2.ID</b> = T8.ID
        WHERE   T1.ID = T2.OID
```

Could anybody point me the right way to avoid this error?

Comment: For starters you should be consistent with your join syntax. And I would recommend using the ANSI-92 style joins (or explicit joins). They have been around now for over 25 years.

Comment: So an inner join, 2 cross joins, and 4 inners?  The order of your joins cause this.  Closed just as I was answering...anything after the t3, will be evaled on it's own.  Use one syntax type, not both...

Comment: Thanks Sean and Twelfth. Really, is better use just one approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, explicit joins are being processed before implicit joins, therefore - `t2.` is not available yet.

Solution: **Avoid** the use of implicit join syntax, and use the proper syntax of joins , just like the second part of your query.

Comment: 100% correct sagi

Comment: I prefer implicit joins for inner joins, but explicit outer joins are much easier to read.  I found I had to place the explicit outer left join syntax directly under the joining table..   FROM a, b, c LEFT OUTER JOIN d ON c.id = d.id   (a and b are invisible to table d)

Comment: Implicit joins are not only harder to read, they are also more prone to errors. You can always use implicit joins but I recommend explicit joins. @RickTilley

Answer (score 0):

The final line:

> WHERE   T1.ID = T2.OID

Is the T2.OID correct? Should it be T2.ID?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct joining syntax as mentioned above. what are the primary/foreign keys?